# Why isn't my application entering my if statement

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm trying to write a console client-server application in Java; using sockets, I currently have a simple login system and a simple command system. The login system appears to work, although it prints the "Invalid username and password" line to the client, regardless whether the user inputs correct credentials. - The connection is definitely working.

However, the command system does not seem to function at all, when the command is received by the server, it does not appear to send anything back.

So my **main question** is why doesn't my server send anything back to the client when the command is received?

Here is my Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer2
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{


    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    String[][] Login = {{"MATT","UNCP"},{"JOHN","UNCP"},{"CARL","UNCP"}};
    String Command;
    String username;
    String username1;
    String password;
    String password1;
    String cmd;
    while(true)
    {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        username = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nUsername received: " + username);
        password = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nPassword received: " + password);
        username1=username.toUpperCase();
        password1=password.toUpperCase();


        for(int i = 0; i<Login.length; i++)
        {
            if(Login[i][0].equals(username1) && Login[i][1].equals(password1))
            {
                outToClient.writeBytes("Hello " + username1);
                outToClient.writeBytes("\nOther users registered on the server currently include: \n");

                for(int k = 0; k<Login.length; k++)
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes(Login[k][0]);
                    }
            }
            else {
                outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.\n");
            }
            }
                        BufferedReader inFromClient2 =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient2 = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        Command = inFromClient2.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nCommand received: " + Command);


if(Command.equals("listTranslations"))
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("English,Thai,Geordie,etc.");
}
else
{
if(Command.equals("getCost"))
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("£100\n");
}
else
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("Invalid Command");
}
}

}

    }
}
```

Here is my client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient2
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
     String userName;
     String passWord;
     String loginInfo;
     String loginInfo2;
     String loginInfo3;
     String command;
     String commandInfo;
     String commandInfo2;

     BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
     DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
     BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

     System.out.println("Username: ");
     userName = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(userName + "\n");

     System.out.println("Password: ");
     passWord = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(passWord + "\n");

     loginInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo);
     loginInfo2 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo2);
     loginInfo3 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo3);

     System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
     command = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(command);

     commandInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(commandInfo);
     commandInfo2 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(commandInfo);



     clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, but i've browsed it a lot in the past. So I just wanted to also say thank you for the great community you provide.

Comment: Also, I just wanted to state. I'm aware this is a bad way to store passwords. This application is for educational purposes so no encryption/hashing is required.

Comment: Welcome! Before looking at your code - did you try to debug it using a debugger built-in into your IDE?

Comment: I would recommend you ditch the 2D array and use a `HashMap` instead. HashMaps allow you to store key value pairs. Once you get the log in name, you just get the value (password) corresponding to the key (login name). The way you are currently doing it will, most likely print `Invalid credentials...` once or twice depending on what user name the user has provided.

Comment: I have, and to no avail. @npinti I have no knowledge of HashMaps, nor will that fix my problem.

Comment: @Catch22: I have included an answer of how I would tackle it to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help you but check if you don't have to flush after each writeBytes call to really outputs data to the client.

try to add  outToClient.flush();

Comment: It seems to repeat the 'invalid username and/or password." line, after I enter a command so I tried adding a outToClient.flush(); after that line, but it still sends the line twice. I think my application may not be entering the if(Command.equals("..")) statement, as the line being sent could be to do with my client sending lines back, or printing received lines more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a continuation from my comment:

This is how I would do it, first I would replace this: `String[][] Login = {{"MATT","UNCP"},{"JOHN","UNCP"},{"CARL","UNCP"}};` by something like so:

```
Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
userDetails.put("MAT", "UNCP");
userDetails.put("JOHN","UNCP"); 
userDetails.put("CARL", "UNCP");
```

Then, instead of this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<Login.length; i++)
        {
            if(Login[i][0].equals(username1) && Login[i][1].equals(password1))
            {
                outToClient.writeBytes("Hello " + username1);
                outToClient.writeBytes("\nOther users registered on the server currently include: \n");

                for(int k = 0; k<Login.length; k++)
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes(Login[k][0]);
                    }
            }
            else {
                outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.\n");
            }
        }
```

I would do this:

```
if (userDetails.get(username1).equals(password1))
{
    outToClient.writeBytes("Hello " + username1);
                outToClient.writeBytes("\nOther users registered on the server currently include: \n");

    for (String str : userDetails.keySet()
    {
         outToClient.writeBytes(str);
    }

}
else
{
    outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.\n");
}
```

The way I am seeing it, the system is both working and printing the `Invalid credentials` string is because, assuming you provide these log in details: `CARL` and `UNCP`, you are passing the 2nd set of credentials, so your loop will check the credentials by comparing them with the first set and since they do not match, it will print the message. On the second iteration, it will see that the credentials match and will log you in.

For more information take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). HashMap is a collection which is usually a good thing to know about, besides the usual `List` and `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try and report back. I assume this to be correct: ;
 Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
 userDetails.put("JOHN","UNCP")("MATT","UNCP")("..","..."); ?? Or would it be ;
 Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
 userDetails.put("JOHN","UNCP","MATT","UNCP");

Comment: @Catch22: I have added more details.

Comment: Thanks, it now seems to work better. Although, it freezes after the login and disconnects when the login credentials are invalid.

Comment: @Catch22: I think you should provide more information. Are you closing the streams once you are done writing and expect the other end to do some response.

Comment: I want it to continue to the if(Command.equals) statement once the user is logged in. I might be asking a lot, and I apologise if I am. Would you mind trying to compile my code and running the client + server? It's very hard for me to explain but you'll see the problem if you compile it.

Comment: @Catch22: You could take a look at the Oracle tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Other than that, since the question now seems to have changed, I would recommend you ask a new question which specifically deals with the problem you are facing.

Comment: The question is still the same. "So my main question is why doesn't my server send anything back to the client when the command is received?" I understand if you don't want to continue helping.

Comment: @Catch22: Sorry my bad. The way I am seeing it, the reason is because you are not closing the streams. The server will *hang* until the stream is closed, since it assumed that more data needs to come. The way I would do it would be to send the login data and close the stream. To send the command the just re-open a new stream and send whatever you need. This will cause the server to stop waiting for the client to send more information.

Comment: So Close the streams if the user is logs in, then reopen it before the if statement? Would I be correct to assume 'DataOutPutStream.close()' would work?

Comment: @Catch22: Send the server the login credentials and close the stream, send the client the information and close the stream, etc. basically open a stream when you need to send stuff and close it when you are done sending and will be expecting a response. I haven't worked with sockets in a while so I recommend you take a look at the tutorial I posted.