# Client-Server Socket: Not reaching if statement

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my application entering my if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516802/why-isnt-my-application-entering-my-if-statement)

I'm trying to write a console client-server application in Java; using sockets, I currently have a simple login system and a simple command system. The login system appears to work, and the connection seems to be working.

However, the command system does not seem to function at all, when the command is received by the server, it does not appear to send anything back.

So my main question is why doesn't my server send anything back to the client when the command is received?

Here is my Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer2
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
//error is caused by command being used differently to login & username/password strings.
//consider removing command as a set string and adding a statement which takes
//the readLine value, adds it to a string and the command is the value of said string.
//If string is = "listLanguages" do this else if = "getcost" do this else "invalid cmd".

    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
userDetails.put("JOHN","UNCP");
userDetails.put("MATT","UNCP");
    String Command;
    String username;
    String username1;
    String password;
    String password1;
    String cmd;
    while(true)
    {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        username = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nUsername received: " + username);
        password = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nPassword received: " + password);
        username1=username.toUpperCase();
        password1=password.toUpperCase();


if (userDetails.get(username1).equals(password1))
{
    outToClient.writeBytes("Hello " + username1);
              outToClient.writeBytes("\nOther users registered on the server currently include: \n");

  for (String str : userDetails.keySet())
  {
      outToClient.writeBytes(str);
  }

}
else
{
   outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.\n");
}

                        BufferedReader inFromClient2 =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient2 = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        Command = inFromClient2.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nCommand received: " + Command);


if(Command.equals("listTranslations"))
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("English,Thai,Geordie,etc.");
}
else
{
if(Command.equals("getCost"))
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("£100\n");
}
else
{
outToClient2.writeBytes("Invalid Command");
}
}

} 

    }
}
```

Here is my client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient2
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
     String userName;
     String passWord;
     String loginInfo;
     String loginInfo2;
     String loginInfo3;
     String command;
     String commandInfo;
     String commandInfo2;

     BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
     DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
     BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

     System.out.println("Username: ");
     userName = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(userName + "\n");

     System.out.println("Password: ");
     passWord = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(passWord + "\n");

     loginInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo);
     loginInfo2 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo2);
     loginInfo3 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(loginInfo3);

     System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
     command = inFromUser.readLine();
     outToServer.writeBytes(command);

     commandInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(commandInfo);
     commandInfo2 = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println(commandInfo);



     clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

Here's how it's supposed to work:
The client connects to the server,
The client asks user to login,
The user inputs his login info,
The server checks the login info,
The server tells the client it's logged in successfully,
The client asks the user to input a command,
The user inputs a command (to request a price),
The command is sent to the server,
The server sends back the desired in info,
It should then loop back to the user being asked to input a command.

However, it does not do this. It gets stuck after the user logs in, on the "Other users registered on the server currently include:" line, without printing any data.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: What if you try to use, in the server, the same inFromClient and outToClient, instead of creating inFromClient2 and outToClient2 ?

Comment: The problem still persists. I have the if statement in the while loop though, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why it's getting stuck is probably because both client and server are on a readLine() resulting in a deadlock. Client waits for incomming data and so is the server, Since this is a command promt client and server, and you have no "button" to send the data with.

I would add info showing which variable it is printing at the moment so you can easily follow where it gets stuck. Example:

```
loginInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
     System.out.println("loginInfo client Side "+loginInfo);
```

This will show you that it's printing the loginInfo variable located in the client. Now you can easily follow the flows and locate where it's going wrong.

I've never done a command promt server/client (only gui), but when you are printing your list of users with your current design, you might want to to build a string with all usernames, send the whole string over to the client, and then the client separates the string with StringBuilder and prints the result. This is because the client will not know how many "usernames" the server will send

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the buffer of the data output stream writer before you send the next line.  I'm also curious why you use two different data output stream writers and input stream readers for one client.  Couldn't you just use the same ones for both parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with improper socket data read/write methods. You have to always flush() when you are writing data to sockets. If you comment line

```
 //loginInfo3 = inFromServer.readLine();
 //System.out.println(loginInfo3);
```

Then you can see that the client displays the "Please enter a command" but after you enter the command the socket is not flushed/closed so the server keeps waiting.

The main issue with the Server and Client code is proper hand shake. You have to write code in a block, open socket, write command, get response and close socket. This should be a common way of entering the data. You have clubbed sockets and writing data to the streams without proper flush/close, hence it is waiting at different points.